# There's something like CameraUpdateFactory to iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to update my camera fitting it to bounds and scrolling it at the same action, but I couldn't achieve it.
If I try to do both at the same time but different animation I get myself in a strange place of the map (iPhone).

The code above works in Simulator, but not in iPhone.

```
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:_restCoord coordinate:_houseCoord];

GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withPadding:190.0f];
[_mapView_ moveCamera:update];

GMSCameraUpdate *downwards = [GMSCameraUpdate scrollByX:0 Y:-90];
[_mapView_ moveCamera:downwards];
```

I saw "CameraUpdateFactory" to Android that could achieve my needs, there's something like that to iOS? I didn't find.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an issue somewhere between a padding value of 150 and 160 on an iPhone. My suspicion is that 160 * 2 = 320, which is approximately the point width of an iPhone, and thus we are asking the map for the bounded area to take up negative space in the map.

This code works:

```
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:_restCoord coordinate:_houseCoord];

GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withPadding:150.0f];
[mapView moveCamera:update];

GMSCameraUpdate *downwards = [GMSCameraUpdate scrollByX:0 Y:-90];
[mapView moveCamera:downwards];
```

Comment: Nop, it still displaying some place in artic. But when I remove the last line, it works.

P.s.: in simulator it works fine, with your code, or mine.

Comment: What happens if you drop the padding to 30.f?

Comment: I did: [_mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:downwards]; and it worked.